# XAML nested DataTemplate data-binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, binding

I have an `ItemsControl` which has its `ItemsSource` set with a `Binding` to an `ObservableCollection` on my `ViewModel`.  I am using a `Button` control within its `ItemTemplate` to display my data and I am using a `DataTemplate` within the `Button` and none of the `Binding` data is being displayed.  Below is the XAML in question:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ConnectedInstruments}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Button.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ModelCode}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SerialNumber}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Button.ContentTemplate>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Neither `TextBlock` controls within the `Button` `DataTemplate` are being populated.  I understand this has something to do with the `Binding` path, however I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong.  Can someone put me on the right track please?

**EDIT**

```
public class Instrument
{
    public string ModelCode { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Instrument> ConnectedInstruments { get; set; }
}
```

I know that the `ItemsControl` is `Binding` correctly with the `ObservableCollection` as the correct count of `Button` controls are being displayed, only the templated data is missing.

Comment: Could you also show your data structure? The viewmodel

Comment: @VidasVasiliauskas - I have added the code in question

Comment: Do you set those values in the run time after the binding applied? Also you do not need Path attribute simply write Text="{Binding ModelCode}"

Comment: @VidasVasiliauskas - I create `Instrument` objects and add them to the `ObservableCollection` in the `VM`s constructor.  If I remove the `Button` control `DataTemplate` and simply set the `Button` `Content="{Binding ModelCode}"` I get output data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any specific reason you need to use `ContentTemplate` instead of directly setting Button's  `Content` like this? :

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ModelCode}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SerialNumber}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```